# Fancyhdr and SBL Hebrew font

Tags: fonts, fancyhdr, hebrew

I wanted to use `fancyhdr` in a document with the [SBL Hebrew](https://www.sbl-site.org/educational/BiblicalFonts_SBLHebrew.aspx) font. However, I get warning messages about undefined font shapes. Please see my example below:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{fontspec,fancyhdr}
\usepackage[nil,bidi=basic]{babel} 
\babelprovide[import]{hebrew}
\setmainfont{SBL Hebrew}[Script=Hebrew] % With other fonts like Arial the warnings disappear

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[C]{\thepage} % When removing C the warnings disappear
\setlength\headheight{12pt}
\setlength\footskip{12pt}

\begin{document}    
שלום    
\end{document}
```

It seems that the error is specific to the SBL Hebrew font and when not all places are used. I guess that there might be some placeholders that are not available in SBL Hebrew. Is there a neat way to do away with these warnings (i.e. not only muting them)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right part of the header shows by default the section title (in article) in a slanted font.

As your font doesn't have this shape you get warnings. Reset this header, e.g. with \fancyhf{}

Answer (score 2):

As Ulrike Fischer correctly answered, the problem is that `fancyhdr` tells TeX to use the slanted series of the main font, and SBC Hebrew does not come with one.  Since you aren’t using the part of the header that takes the slant, her answer is great.

I’d still like to supplement her answer with an alternative solution.

```
\documentclass{article}
\tracinglostchars=2 % Warn if a glyph gets dropped!
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[nil,bidi=basic]{babel} 
\usepackage{fontspec} % Better to load this after babel?

\babelprovide[import,main,onchar=ids fonts]{hebrew}

\babelfont{rm}
          [Scale=1.0,
           ItalicFont=*,
           ItalicFeatures={FakeSlant=-0.125}, % Italic in a RTL language should slant left.
           Language=Default % Suppress harmless warning.
          ]{SBL_Hbrw.ttf}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[C]{\thepage} % When removing C the warnings disappear
\setlength\headheight{12pt}
\setlength\footskip{12pt}

\begin{document}    
שלום
\textit{חברים}
\end{document}
```

[image: SBL Hebrew sample]

This uses the `FakeSlant=` feature of `fontspec` to create a slanted version of the font, with the slant from right to left.  (I don’t think there’s a consensus in Israel about how to handle italics, either.)  You might or might not like the results.  You could also select a matching font as the `ItalicFont`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Here are a few things to consider before making the choice: https://ubuntu.com/blog/which-way-to-slant-the-hebrew